# Corner div is not filling a parent div with a radius corner

Tags: html, css

I child `div` is not being able to fill the corner of a parent div with a `border-radius`.

See the top right corner of this picture

[image]

```css
.outer {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.corner {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="corner">Corner Element
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: Did you mean a bit red color in the top right corner?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov yes

Answer (score 4):

You can add a small padding and make the background to cover only the content.

```css
.outer {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: red content-box;
  padding:1px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.corner {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="corner">Corner Element
  </div>
</div>
```

Or disable the coloration in that corner with a gradient:

```css
.outer {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg,transparent 20px,red 0);
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.corner {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="corner">Corner Element
  </div>
</div>
```